# Двоеточие при распространении мысли в БСП

Tags: двоеточие, редактура, бессоюзное

Стояла морозная погода, кругом всё было белым-бело: ветер кружил в воздухе снежинки и опускал их на землю. Правильно ли поставить двоеточие перед описанием или лучше заменить на запятую?

Comment: *Поставить двоеточие или лучше заменить на двоеточие* - может, на тире? И "опуска**л**."

Comment: Предлагаете тире?

Comment: Просто говорю, что во втором предложении, скорее всего, ошибка. Почему там слово "двоеточие" два раза?

Comment: Ах, да, спасибо, исправила)

Comment: И там ещё не "опуская", а "опускал" - одна буква. К тому же само описание начинается не в конце, а после "морозная погода".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***(1) Стояла морозная погода, (2) кругом всё было белым-бело: (3) ветер кружил в воздухе снежинки и опускал их на землю.***

Предложение нужно редактировать, ни один из знаков не подходит.

Неясно, почему всё белым-бело. Уже намело много снега и он лежит всюду? Но тогда предложение 3 не распространяет предложение 2. Или белым-бело в воздухе, потому что идет снег? Но тогда об этом надо сказать отдельно.

В качестве варианта:

***Стояла морозная погода, кругом всё  было уже белым-бело, а снег всё продолжал идти: ветер кружил в воздухе снежинки и плавно опускал их на землю.***

Comment: Ветер не является причиной снега. И без ветра снег не остановится и будет идти... Поэтому двоеточие не подходит в изменённом варианте.

Comment: А при чем тут причина? Двоеточие имеет и другие функции, в частности ставится при раскрытии содержания. Предложение 4 как раз раскрывает содержание предложения 3, рисует "картинку".  От общего "снег идет" мы переходим к тому, как это выглядит. Предложение 4 слишком конкретно, поэтому текст смотрится странно.

Comment: Розенталя читайте, все остальные правила - это пересказ. 1. Между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится двоеточие, если вторая часть (одно или несколько предложений) раскрывает содержание первой части (между частями можно вставить слова а именно): Погода была ужасная: ветер выл, мокрый снег падал хлопьями http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150

Comment: Просто сделал для себя вывод, что во всех таких случаях к первой части можно задать вопрос "почему?". Не видел ещё предложений, где бы этот вопрос не подходил. В примере про погоду подходит, но про снег - нет.

Comment: Вывод неправильный. У двоеточия три функции: обозначение причины, пояснительная (раскрытие содержания) и изъяснительная.  Это общеизвестная истина. А по поводу снега и погоды Вы можете иметь собственное мнение, но я лично его не разделяю.

Comment: В большинстве примеров Розенталя вопрос "почему?" подходит. В остальных можно вставить "а именно". Но со снегом так не получается. Да и обязательно наличие логической связи между простыми предложениями. А снег будет продолжать идти и без ветра. Во всех примерах Розенталя можно задать вопрос к какому-то слову, а вторая часть на него отвечает. То есть слово разъясняется. Но в примере про снег не получается задать вопрос. Там просто продолжается повествование.

Comment: Какой вопрос, о чем Вы? Сначала говорится, что идет снег, а потом рассказывается подробно, как это происходит, это и есть раскрытие содержания. Снег может просто идти, но если дует ветер, то  снежинки кружатся в воздухе, прежде чем упасть. Именно это раскрытие содержания и было в авторском тексте, но там не хватало общего названия процесса (снег идет), предложение (3) на эту роль не годилось.

Comment: Ну тогда да. Если так, то можно задать вопрос. Раз ветер влияет на то, каким образом идёт снег (ровно или кружась). Так сразу и не догадаться об этой связи, которая относится к глаголу "идти". Но тут довольно спорно. В примерах Розенталя все взаимоотношения явные, и там вообще нет ничего, к чему можно было бы придраться.

Comment: Придираться и критиковать все умеют. Все знают, как не надо делать. А вот вы попробуйте написать правильное предложение, безупречное с точки зрения художественной стилистики. То есть во вотром ответе представьте нам отредактированный вариант, объясните ваши логические связи, которые вы так ясно видите, на конкретном примере.

Comment: Явные связи - это когда правильность и оптимальность знака бесспорна. В вашем варианте также и запятая подходит. Я считаю, что в моём ответе лучший вариант, так как  "Стояла морозная погода", а потом двоеточие и разъясняются или даже перечисляются особенности этой погоды. В этом месте "а именно" подходит больше всего. В таком варианте предложение очень естественно смотрится.

Comment: Тогда уж напишите сначала так: Стояла зима. Потому что все сказанное далее имеет отношение не к морозу, а к снегу и ветру.

Comment: Не согласен, что не имеет отношения к морозу. Когда дует ветер, всегда гораздо холоднее. А снег - это последствие низкой температуры. Даже можно сказать, что снег - это элемент мороза. Сам снег также охлаждает окружающий воздух. Не говорю, что предложение идеально. Но логика есть вполне.

Comment: @Sharon, ваш вариант предложения мне очень понравился. Когда я придумала это предложение( а  с него начинается вся книга),  я  думала, что читателю всё и так ясно.( Всё белым- бело, потому что много снега на земле). Но вы показали недочеты в предложении, которые до этого  я не замечала. И еще я поняла, что надо обязательно приобрести книгу Розенталя.

Comment: Да, конечно, Розенталь - это основной и официальный источник, обычно на него делаются все ссылки. Но зачем его приобретать, он же есть в Сети в открытом доступе. http://old-rozental.ru/

Answer (score 0):

Двоеточие при описании ставится после глаголов:

`Пополз я по густой траве вдоль по оврагу, смотрю: лес кончился, несколько казаков выезжают из него на поляну, и вот выскакивает прямо к ним мой Карагёз...` (Лермонтов)

`Я знаю: в вашем сердце есть и гордость, и прямая честь.` (Пушкин)

`Павел чувствует: чьи-то пальцы дотрагиваются до его руки выше локтя.` (Островский)

(но суть тут не в описании, а в перечислении элементов, на которых направлено действие)

Источник: https://therules.ru/colon/ (тут же все правила двоеточия)

Само описание начинается после "Стояла морозная погода". Описание должно начинаться после общих фраз, таких, как эта. Вторая фраза не является общей, это уже, скорее всего, и есть описание.

Но здесь есть **перечисление** особенностей погоды, и как раз после общего слова (`погода`). Поэтому лучше поставить двоеточие после первой части:

`Стояла морозная погода: кругом всё было белым-бело, ветер кружил в воздухе снежинки и опускал их на землю.`

Comment: @NaraMamedova Если хотите менять только данный знак. --- 3 часть не объясняет 2 часть. Без ветра всё равно будет бело, если идёт снег. Двоеточие там не подходит. Там продолжается повествование и подходит запятая.

Answer (score -1):

> Стояла морозная погода, кругом всё было белым-бело: ветер кружил в
>   воздухе снежинки и опускал их на землю. Правильно ли поставить
>   двоеточие перед описанием или лучше заменить на запятую?

Авторский выбор. Здесь есть основания для двоеточия (вторя часть фразы объясняет первую), но насколько это соответствует замыслу автора, решать только ему.

Я лично не могу отдать предпочтения ни одному из вариантов.

(+)

Правило здесь не связано с тем, после какого слова идет двоеточие:

> Двоеточие ставится после предложения, за которым следует одно или
>   несколько предложений, не соединённых с первым посредством союзов и
>   заключающих в себе:
>
> а) разъяснение или раскрытие содержания того, о чём говорится в первом 
>   предложении, например:
>
> Я не ошибся: старик не отказался от предлагаемого стакана (Пушкин).
>
> Сверх того, заботы большого семейства беспрестанно мучили её: то кормление
>   грудного ребёнка не шло, то нянька ушла, то, как теперь,
>   заболел один из детей (Л. Толстой).
>
> Тут открылась картина довольно занимательная: широкая сакля, которой крыша опиралась на два закопчённые столба, была полна народа
>   (Лермонтов).
>
> б) основание, причина того, о чём говорится в первом предложении, например:
>
> Не нагнать тебе бешеной тройки: кони сыты, и крепки, и бойки (Некрасов).
>
> Недаром боги греческие признавали над собою неотразимую власть судьбы: судьба
>    — это была та тёмная граница, за которую не переступало
>   сознание древних (Белинский).

Comment: а какой бы знак вы посоветовали выбрать?

Comment: Не буду советовать. Я не знаю, как мыслит автор. Если он он "перечисляет" события то запятая. Если же объясняет первое через второе, то двоеточие, естественно.